# Why is render() throwing this error: ':' expected

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Error `':' expected` appears in render method and points at `&&`. `this.state.obj` has type `MyType`.

```
type MyType = {
    name: string,
};

constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       obj: null
   };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({obj: {name: 'Vasya'}});
}

render() {
    return {this.state.obj && <MyComponent />};
}
```

Comment: You're not inside JSX there, `{` doesn't begin interpolation; `return {` is starting an *object*.

Answer (score 1):

You have badly implemented a return statement - use bracket `return ()` instead of curly braces. Using `return {}`, you are returning an object.
Also, notice that it's better if you destructure data from the state before you render.

```
render() {
    const {obj} = this.state;
    return (obj && <MyComponent />);
}
```

Comment: why is it better to destructure data from state before rendering? Just curious!

Comment: There are several reasons. It is more readable when you have multiple variables in the render method or whenever. 
eg. `const {foo, bar, user, data} = this.state`.

without this, you will always have to type `this.state.user`   `this.state.data`
It's very repetitive, and you don't want to repeat unnecessary code.

Comment: Hope that helped you @Smarticles101

Answer (score 0):

`return` is returning an object, not jsx. Try this

```
type MyType = {
    name: string,
};

constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       obj: null
   };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({obj: {name: 'Vasya'}});
}

render() {
    return (
        {this.state.obj && <MyComponent />}
    );
}
```

or this:

```
type MyType = {
    name: string,
};

constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       obj: null
   };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({obj: {name: 'Vasya'}});
}

render() {
    if (this.state.obj)
        return <MyComponent />;
    else
        return null;
}
```